# how to redirect to my custom 404 error page if subdirectory not present

Tags: .htaccess, joomla2.5

I have joomla site and I have custom 404 error page.
Which works correctly if there is no file present.
ex: `my-domain.com/aaa`
then it shows custom 404 page correctly with URL: `my-domain.com/error-404.html`

But when sub-directory is not present (ex: `my-domain.com/aaa/`) then it not shows it properly as URL changes to my-domain.com/aaa/error-404.html

I want to redirect to my 404 error page if sub-directory name typed is not present.

Answer (score 2):

this is what I do in Joomla 2.5

- create your custom '404' article
- create a new unpublished menu item which links to this your custom 404 article and apply your changes. Copy the URL for this page (index.php?optio...)
- in your Joomla installation, copy the error.php file from the templates/system directory to your template directory.
- edit this error.php file (which you just copied to your template directory) and add the following code immediately under the 'restricted access' line:

  if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
  header('Location: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=...');
  exit;
  }

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I have this custom error page already.. But that display if there is no file found..ex: domain.com/aa. But it not works when directory is not present. ex: domain.com/aa/

Comment: I suspect you have a static non-joomla 404 page and the behaviour you are seeing is standard if you are using .htaccess to manage the 404 redirect. While it's not the only way to do this, you will find that the method I describe above will completely solve your problem and it gives you lots of flexibliity. You can custom design your error page so it matches the rest of your site.

Comment: Works well for me on 2.5 with SEF URL turned on. Just name your page "page-not-found" in the alias of your Hidden Menu item and point it to your article. Thanks.